# facebook app requires me to add a platform when I don't have one

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building a simple Facebook app to connect the backend of a project to Facebook Messenger.
I am trying to send my app for review but it requires me to send a platform for the reviewer to test my app on.
the only place to interact with the app is the test Facebook page i created but i cannot add Facebook urls to the platform. What am I doing wrong here or what am I supposed to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you login?

Answer (score 1):

> I am building a simple Facebook app to connect the backend of a project to Facebook Messenger.

If you don’t have any end-user facing frontend, this would be considered a “server-to-server” app.

The documentation has specific instructions on how to submit those: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/server-to-server-apps

> **Platform**
> Platform refers to the platform that your app users use to interact with your app. Since your app does not have an interface and your users don't interact with it directly, set this to Website and provide the URL to your company's website.

(Make sure to properly describe the purpose of your app and how it works, so that the reviewer does not try to go to that URL and look for a login button there.)